# Best practice for Python-based Salt-stack project

Tags: python, devops, salt-stack

I am a SaltStack user. When I am playing with those YAML files (and jinja templates), I am always wondering that maybe building the SaltStack project just with Python is more clear. But all advanced samples I can find are building multiple sls YAML files that work together for provision and event reaction.

Is there any practical way to code a SaltStack project mainly with Python instead of YAML files?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use python instead of yaml. All Salt really cares about is the resulting data structure.

Here's the general documentation on renderers:
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/

Here's the documentation on the pure Python renderer: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.py.html#module-salt.renderers.py

The PyObjects renderer: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.pyobjects.html

And the PyDSL renderer:  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.pydsl.html

One of those should get you what you want.